# How to tweet a message containing a custom URL to Twitter?

Tags: twitter-oauth, custom-url

Whenever I try to tweet a message containing a custom URL to Twitter using oAuth, the message is posted as plain text including all HTML tags
For example I want show the message as:

```
this is mysample tweet.
and this is my link: <a href ="www.example.com">my web address</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter doesn't support rich text, it is plain text only. You especially can't set the link text for a URL. The only possibility which could come close is to use the [cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) feature for supported clients.

Comment: Thanks. yes I haven't been able to get a clue yet, but I need this one badly..there must be workaround

Comment: There is none. And that's the whole point of Twitter compared to e.g. Tumblr.

Comment: Unable to find a solution I have decided to go with bit.ly, ie for short and i will place that url beside my custom link. Anyway, Thanks for your help.